# Title Tag shown in Body

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

i have written the following basic HTML code including bootstrap 3.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
        <title>Title</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
        <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Custom Style for this page -->
        <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="site-wrapper">
            <!-- Navigation -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">MEDIFAKTOR server</a>
                </div> <!-- Navbar Header -->
            </nav>
        </div> <!-- Site Wrapper -->
    </body>
</html>
```

But whatever I change, the title is being displayed in the Body of the document as well. I checked for missing tags. Do I miss something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Close your viewport meta tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```